# How to retrieve all contacts' details from Windows Contacts programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, contacts

I have an application in which I want my control (maybe listbox) to be populated with the contact's name and number present in the Windows Contacts (present in Windows 7). How is this possible?

Comment: Please don't add things like "(C#, .NET)" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use this feature in Windows 7. It was introduced in Vista and soon got deprecated in Windows Server 2008.

Any way, [here is the entrance to **C++** API section (that also explains the Contacts schema) at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735779%28VS.85%29.aspx).

But for managed code, you should use the Contacts.Net project [here at codeplex](http://contacts.codeplex.com/). Here is a simple example that enumerates contacts:

```
//using Microsoft.Communications.Contacts;

ContactManager theContactManager = new ContactManager();
foreach (Contact theContact in theContactManager.GetContactCollection())
{
    string theLine = theContact.Names[0].FormattedName;
    foreach(PhoneNumber theNumber in theContact.PhoneNumbers)
        theLine += "\t" + theNumber.ToString();
    listBox1.Items.Add(theLine);
    //Console.WriteLine(theLine); //Uncomment this if on console
}
```